# Site Column Get Managed Property for it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am building custom windows application and needed filter functionality and wondering if is there way to get managed property name for site column so I can include in search query?

Is there a SharePoint 2013 server side API that gets as input a name of a site column and returns the name of the corresponding ManagedProperty?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by navigating to the list-settings in SharePoint. Click the column, and at the end of the URL, you can see the internal column-name. In the below URL, the name is "Title".

/_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7BD6F36FA5%2D5BF6%2D41BF%2DBC43%2DC1AE7EFFE830%7D&Field=**Title**